# How to trace a ASP.NET Security Exception

Tags: asp.net, security, debugging, hosting

How can I figure out what is actually causing the following error? The page is the same as other pages but for some reason, only this page is having this error. It also only happens on the ISP (GoDaddy) who has a trust level of Medium and I can't set a breakpoint and try to catch it.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

```
Stack Trace:

    [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
       System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
       System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +59
       System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() +54
       hh.a(Int32 A_0, Boolean A_1, Boolean A_2) +20
       jg.b(c A_0, UInt64 A_1) +234
       ei.b(c A_0, UInt64 A_1) +18
       jg.a(c A_0, UInt64 A_1, Boolean A_2) +61
```

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.1433; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.1433
```

If you have had this issue or just know how I can fix or trace it please add your answer. Trust level of Medium is required by the ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a local instance of IIS and setting the trust level to medium? That would help you debug and try stuff a little quicker.

(And is a good habit to get into anyway. You want to test in an environment as close to production as possible. And the VS web server definitely has a few important differences that can get you if you don't test in IIS too.)

Comment: So how would I lower my required trust level in the site? Say I'm using Db4o, which requires me to load a file in the file system..

Comment: For IIS7, you can edit the Trust Level in the IIS Manager under the ".NET Trust Levels" item at either the server or web site level. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753658(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I know how to change the trust, but what if I lower it and then get errors. Where do I go from there?

Comment: If after testing the lower trust level you find that a library breaks, you have to either use another library, a different method in that library that doesn't require the higher trust, or work with the library vendor to rewrite the code to work under the available trust level. 
Or, move the application to a server/host that allows for the higher level of trust the library currently requires.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe GoDaddy supports Full trust - though that may have changed recently. The error is caused by the [System.IO.Path.GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx) call, which requires [EnvironmentPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.environmentpermission.aspx).

The call stack prior to that is obfuscated, so my guess is it's from a component vendor. Check for an update or fix for partial trust from them, or replace it.

Comment: there was a DevExpress component on that page but I remvd it yet the error never resolved. I changed the web.config hoping it would recompile. Is there any other way to force the page to compile on a remote host? My last option is to recreate the page never having that component and see what happens

Comment: That should have cause a recompile. Check that you aren't also caching the page. If not, then you probably still have the error and it wasn't that component.

Answer (score 0):

Setting breakpoints in obfuscated, non-debug assemblies are hard. It will likely lead you nowhere.

Find out why the obfuscated component is trying to access the temp path.